# Fast iteration over columns of a matrix with ctypes

Tags: python, numpy, ctypes

let A be a matrix

```
import numpy as np
A = np.matrix([[3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 0.0], [2.0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0], [0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 3.0]])

[[ 3.  1.  2.  0.]
 [ 2.  1.  3.  1.]
 [ 0.  2.  0.  3.]]
```

I am facing a complex library (based on the ctypes interface) that is excepting me giving pointers to the columns of the matrix, e.g.:

```
import ctypes

for j in range(0,4):
    a = np.copy(A[:,j])
    lib.DoSomething(a.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)))
```

Obviously I am keen to avoid the copying of the column into the variable a. I guess there are numerous clever ideas? Maybe I should transpose and copy the matrix? Or is there a way I can enfore to store it columnbased?

Thomas

Comment: @ebarr yes it can, it's just not the default. See Davidmh's answer.

Comment: What you are saying applies to modifying the strides. If you go to the doc of array, "If order is ‘C’ (default), then the array will be in C-contiguous order (last-index varies the fastest). If order is ‘F’, then the returned array will be in Fortran-contiguous order (first-index varies the fastest)." The speed difference is due to the actual memory layout of the data.

Comment: @Davidmh Apologies, you are spot on. I was misunderstanding the docs, but just doing a quick test I see that it works fine. I've deleted my original comment so that people don't get lead astray.

Comment: The precise tpye in the argtpyes is ctypes.POINTER(ctpyes.c_double), I have no chance to change this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store the matrix in Fortran order, so the columns are contiguous. Then just pass a view to that contiguous column.

```
A = np.array([[3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 0.0], [2.0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0], [0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 3.0]], order='F')
for j in range(0, 4):
    a = A[:, j]
```

Also, avoid using `np.matrix` unless you really really need it. It is a bug magnet.

Answer (score 2):

<del>So numpy will only store your data in row-major order. If you want to avoid the copy operation you can do:</del>

EDIT: So the above statement is nonsense and the simple answer it just to set `order='F'` as in the above answer.

```
import numpy as np

# avoid matrix and define the dtype at the start so you don't have an extra copy
A = np.array([[3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 0.0], [2.0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0], [0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 3.0]],dtype="float64",order="F")

for row in A.transpose():
    lib.DoSomething(np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(row))
```

Comment: Numpy can store data in row and colum-major order. See the docs: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html

And you are not avoiding the copy, you are just doing it all together, thus duplicating the memory required (but perhaps better performance, I haven't checked).